# Is there a way to configure the animation set on UI-bootstrap's carousel component?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, css-animations

An example of the standard configuration is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ti3WexpMMQ5tZHB8oQjQ?p=preview). Its crazy how limited the documentation is for many of the features that the UIB team created...

I was wondering if anyone here has experience with changing the animation during slide transition. I was hoping to do some custom tweaking to the current animation settings but cant find an example of anyone accomplishing this.

All I have found is that the `no-transition` property accepts a boolean to toggle the slide animation...

Comment: perhaps this is not possible?

Comment: I don't see an API for making these kinds of changes, but you might be able to hack the [implementation of carousel](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js#L277)...

Answer (score 0):

That angular-ui-bootstrap animations are actually the TWBS css transitions defined in the carousel.less [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/carousel.less). See the .item rule that starts on line 11. The angular-ui-bootstrap carousel directive simply adds/removes the next/prev/right/left classes.